# R - calculate/evaluate a time series model on a specific day

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting, lm

I have used a look-back window to perform a multiple linear regression on a zoo data frame like the one below:

> ```
> df
>                       y            X1           X2            X3          X4
> 2015-01-05 -0.017697886 -0.0303143773 -0.037748414 -2.015346e-02  0.12078726
> 2015-01-06  0.026334273 -0.0003695332 -0.005050541 -7.924213e-03 -0.02709586
> 2015-01-07 -0.033780880  0.0051106504  0.006257167  8.340199e-03 -0.02316465
> 2015-01-08  0.012420844  0.0330091413  0.035152040  2.311611e-02 -0.08373201
> 2015-01-09 -0.005641188 -0.0194103325 -0.029843684 -1.053020e-02  0.10505671
> 2015-01-12 -0.005053201  0.0137312764  0.013474812  4.306844e-05  0.03234955
> 2015-01-13  0.011951128  0.0161338800  0.015979652  6.252886e-03 -0.04066445
> 2015-01-14 -0.023470817 -0.0125438934 -0.014201182 -2.378026e-02  0.03254407
> 2015-01-15  0.014655518  0.0217170617  0.021671946  1.712123e-02 -0.01567272
> ```

I regressed y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 using lm:

> `lm <- lm(df[,1] ~ df[,-1])`

and obtained the best fitting parameters:

```
> coef(sum_lm)
                             Estimate  Std. Error   t value   Pr(>|t|)
    (Intercept)           -0.02360827 0.007349594 -3.212187 0.03252117
    merge_n.tmp[, -1]X1   8.99408519 2.341094738  3.841829 0.01843072
    merge_n.tmp[, -1]X2 -7.13439870 1.913985874 -3.727509 0.02034096
    merge_n.tmp[, -1]X3  -0.91469896 0.640218236 -1.428730 0.22628243
    merge_n.tmp[, -1]X4  -0.17417599 0.133629611 -1.303424 0.26238975
```

Now I want to evaluate y at a given day where I do have the values of X1, X2, X3, X4. For example: what's the value of my best-fitting model on 2015-01-15 knowing that:

```
X1(2015-01-15) = 0.0217170617  
X2(2015-01-15) = 0.021671946  
X3(2015-01-15) = 1.712123e-02 
X4(2015-01-15) = -0.01567272
```

I can write a little script that does it but before I wanted to ask whether there is a function in R that allows me to do this directly, w/o scripting/looping etc.

EXTENSION TO THE PREVIOUS QUESTION:
Another question is: what if I want to predict ahead in the future? `predict` gives me a problem when I input data frames with different dates than df.

Comment: The function `predict` is used to test model with new data , see help and examples of `?predict.lm`

Comment: @OdeToMyFiddle what if I want to predict ahead in the future? `predict` gives me a problem when I input data frames with different dates than df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the generic function `predict()`, try to look at the help page `?predict` and `?predict.lm`. A small example follows:

```
## lets make up some data and fit model:
library(zoo)
myTs <- zoo(mtcars, seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), length.out = nrow(mtcars), by = 1))
fit <- lm(mpg ~  cyl + disp, data = myTs)
```

Now we predict on all existing observations:

```
> predict(fit)
2016-01-01 2016-01-02 2016-01-03 2016-01-04 2016-01-05 2016-01-06 2016-01-07 2016-01-08 
  21.84395   21.84395   26.08886   19.82676   14.55267   20.50602   14.55267   25.29227 
2016-01-09 2016-01-10 2016-01-11 2016-01-12 2016-01-13 2016-01-14 2016-01-15 2016-01-16 
  25.41371   21.68752   21.68752   16.28581   16.28581   16.28581   12.24731   12.49431 
2016-01-17 2016-01-18 2016-01-19 2016-01-20 2016-01-21 2016-01-22 2016-01-23 2016-01-24 
  12.90598   26.69196   26.75371   26.84839   25.83979   15.41718   15.70536   14.75851 
2016-01-25 2016-01-26 2016-01-27 2016-01-28 2016-01-29 2016-01-30 2016-01-31 2016-02-01 
  13.72933   26.68578   25.83568   26.35438   14.73792   22.15271   15.76711   25.82127
```

or for a new observation using the newdata argument:

```
predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(cyl = 6, disp = 180))
21.43228
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I want to predict ahead in time? `predict` gives me a problem when I input data frames with different dates than df

Comment: It sounds like your are using dates as input, I think you might want to convert your dates into time (integer) before fitting the linear model, eg. days from a certain starting point, time = myDates - as.Date("2000-01-01"). If you use `as.integer(myDates)` this amounts to "1970-01-01" as starting point. Afterwards you will be able to use the above as usual.

Answer (score 0):

`modelr::add_predictions(df, lm)` will augment your data frame with the fitted values. If you also want confidence intervals, you can use `ciTools::add_ci(df, lm)`.

Edit: Never mind. Apparently zoo data frames aren't supported by these packages.

Comment: Thanks @mavery, but this does not seem to work. In addition to your example I also tried to rename the lm formula with the actual variables names, i.e. `lm(y ~ X1+X2+X3+X4, data=df)` instead of using `lm(df[,1] ~ df[,-1])`, and also tried to use `add_predictions(coredata(df), lm)` in addition to `add_predictions(df, lm)`, but I get these errors:
"Error in data[[var]] <- stats::predict(model, data): more elements supplied than there are to replace"
"Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels):'data' must be a data.frame, not a matrix or an array"

Comment: a simple `predict(lm, df)` does the job